# How to Redirect to other page if MVC Routing fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my `RouteConfig.cs` and i am using `isValidAppId` class to match the `appid` which comes in `url` to the 'modelApplicationId' which i have stored in `web.config`

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               "ApplicationRoute",
               "{appId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Account", action = "SignIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
               new {
                   isValidAppId = new isValidAppId() 
               }
           );
        }
    }

    public class isValidAppId : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            var isValid = false;
            if (values["appId"] != null && WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModelApplicationId"] != null)
            {
                if (values["appId"].ToString() == WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModelApplicationId"].ToString())
                    return isValid = true;
            }

            // return true if this is a valid AppId
            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

If the *isValidAppId returns false* i want to redirect to other `Error.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, If the `isValidAppId` `returns false` then you just `throw an custom Exception / HttpException` which will automatically redirect to `Error.cshtml` page with your custom error message.

```
if(!isValid) // If isValid is false
{
   throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound"); // Modify According to your custom message.
}

// return true if this is a valid AppId
return isValid;
```

**Update:**

In order to redirect to `Error.cshtml` page. Just follow the below code...

I have created the Error Controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have the below piece of code in `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("/Error/Error");
}
```

I have created the `Error.Cshtml` inside **shared folder** of my MVC project.

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Error.</h1>
    <h2 class="error">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
</hgroup>
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: yes i got you thanks but how can i redirect to Error.chsml after throwing exception it is stoping at that point only

Comment: @SyedRasheed I have updated my answer. let me know in case if there is any issue. :)

Comment: Thanks this is what i actually wanted :)

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help :).,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways, it depends on what you prefer or need. You can use the httpContext to redirect to the page that you want. You may use some of the Redirection methods of the HttpContext.Response object.

[image]

Comment: could you please tell me at where should i keep this code?

Comment: You could place this on the Match method. Use the httpContext from the parameter.